# Forget password link from SSO does not redirect back to callback url

Tags: single-sign-on, callback, forgot-your-password

We have set up a connected app in Salesforce and configured a callback url for integration with a separate authentication management system.

When logging in from our application, upon successful authentication the user is directed back to our application.

However, when the user clicks the "forgot password" button, there seems to be no information regarding the state, and the user is redirected back to the Salesforce homepage.

When using SSO, how is it possible to ensure when coming from our application, upon resetting their password the user is successfully redirected back to the application?

Comment: It's unclear what UX you have in mind - SSO and Reset Password are operations that aren't connected to each other, at least not usually.  In general any sort of "custom" flow requires you to build your own pages that use SF APIs underneath the hood.

Comment: Hi there, thanks, I had suspected that this was something that was not supported out of the box by Salesforce, and your comment seems to confirm this.
I guess a custom flow using the API would be the best way forward - thanks for your response.

Comment: Check the new [headless Forgot Password flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_headless_identity_pointer.htm&type=5&release=242) in Spring '23.